# Run ansible playbook against Windows and then start another Playbook

Tags: azure-devops, ansible

I am running an Ansible Playbook that builds a VMware machine from an iso using ADO pipelines and it's exceeding the time allowed to run (60 minutes) so I want to break it up into two different playbooks and ADO pipelines. My question is how would I pass the randomly generated machine name to the second playbook/pipeline?

Comment: What have you tried and what error is it producing for you? As written, it sounds like "write code for me" which is not how this site works

Comment: Not looking for the code. I am just trying to understand how to pass that variable or how to collect it from the other playbook/pipeline. Normally I'd pass it when I called the second playbook but since this will be a separate pipeline I am drawing a blank on how to do it.  I don't even have a starting point. I am new to this so if there is even just a link to something that would guide me? I have searched for this and can't find anyone talking about how they did this and I am very new to ansible and ADO